# Can you use masks with meshgrid?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I am using numpy.meshgrid to evaluate some points in an image. However, with a big image I get memory problems because the meshgrid has to be so big. I don't actually need the whole meshgrid, since I mask the result into a small shape.

**Edit:**

Here is a small example:

```
nrows = 10000
ncols = 10000
mask = ma.array(np.zeros((nrows,ncols)), dtype = bool)
mask[1000:1500,1000:1500] = True

xvals = np.linspace(0,ncols,ncols)
yvals = np.linspace(0,nrows,nrows)

gridX, gridY = np.meshgrid(xvals,yvals)

gridX2 = ma.array(gridX, mask = mask)
gridY2 = ma.array(gridY, mask = mask)

outArr[mask] = evalFunc(gridX2,gridY2,params)
```

As you can see the meshgrid is huge, but the mask is a lot smaller. This is just a theoretical example and in reality the mask is not a rectangle.

So here is my question:

Can I get numpy.meshgrid to create the meshgrid ONLY inside the mask, so it doesn't need to use space on the rest of the pixels??

Comment: Are you looking for `np.nonzero(mask)`?

Comment: Masked arrays always use as much space as their data, irrespective of the mask. If you did avoid "creating" the meshgrid outside the mask, you'd still be using just as much space storing `0`